# Will reinstalling Windows 7 permanently delete all data on HDD?

Tags: windows, reinstall

My PC is infected with a Shortcut Virus and needs a complete wipe, so I decided to reinstall Windows 7 from a USB drive containing an ISO file.

However, I want all the data on all the partitions of the device (including C) to be completely and permanently deleted/removed/shredded (or whatever it's called).

Will reinstalling windows 7 give me that?

There are no important data on the device, so nothing of value can be lost.

Comment: Windows 7 will ask you if you want to keep your personal files of C, if you choose no it will delete everything in C and proceed to installation. You have to manually delete your data in local drives. They are not affected with reinstallation of operating system.

Comment: see also https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now/138617

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: if you format the drive and choose to delete existing partitions and recreate them, then that will remove that particular virus.

Keep in mind, however, that doing this does not resolve a rootkit on your drive if you are concerned about rootkits.

You mention having the data "completely and permanently removed".  That is pretty strong.  That statement, to a security person, implies doing a DOD-grade wipe of the drive.  That's possible using DBAN, but would take a long time and probably be overkill for your case.